# Передача кириллицы чрез cURL (C++)

Tags: c++, http, кодировка, curl, кириллица

В нижеприведённом коде я пытаюсь отправить запрос к GoogleSearchAPI через cURL. Строка запроса (url) содержит **кириллические символы, которые при отправке непонятно как кодируются**, и ни Fiddler ни GoogleAPI не могут понять что это. Как бороться с такой проблемой?

```
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <clocale>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    string question = "привет";

    string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=" + question;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://192.167.1.106:8888/");
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

Fiddler видит этот запрос так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В url допустим лишь ограниченный набор символов (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-`, `.`, `_`, `~`), все остальные символы должны быть закодированы т.н. [url-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) кодировкой. Для этого можно использовать функцию [curl_easy_escape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html).

Далее, сервис который будет парсить url на той стороне, должен понимать кодировку в которой изначально был текст. Обычно сервис ожидает какую-то конкретную кодировку. И скорее всего, это будет UTF-8. У вас же текст в Windows-1251. Соответственно, предварительно вам нужно перекодировать текст в utf-8.

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::string to_utf8(const std::wstring &str)
{
    static std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> u8;
    return u8.to_bytes(str);
}

string s = to_utf8(L"привет");

char *question = curl_easy_escape(curl, s.c_str(), 0);
if (question) {
  ...
  curl_free(question);
}
```

Comment: Кириллические буквы превратились в код, но GoogleAPI по прежнему не понимает что это

Comment: @avalanche_of_misery Обновил ответ.

Comment: в разных частях url разные могут быть допустимые символы, важно что не-ascii символы гарантированно [percent-encoding требуют](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1). Чтобы не думать, части query всегда можно в curl_easy_escape() передавать¶ Можно `u8"привет"` c++11 синтаксис попробовать, чтобы компилятор в utf-8 превращал.

Comment: @jfs, хорошее решение! Жаль, что только один ответ можно отметить как лучший